# Select only alphabetic prefix from a column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a regex expression I need to convert to a sql server query.  The goal is to select the alphabetic prefix from a column, so `AAA-1234BC` would become `AAA`, `ABC123` would become `ABC` and `1234A` would become `''`.

From my understanding, regex isnt natively supported in SQL server, so I am wondering if there is another purely sql way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `PATINDEX` here:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    CASE WHEN col LIKE '[A-Z]%'
         THEN LEFT(col, PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%', col) - 1)
         ELSE '' END AS first_alpha
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The above logic finds, in the case of strings which do begin with a letter, the index of the first *non* letter character, and then takes a substring from the first letter until before that first non letter.  Otherwise, it returns empty string.